# Json.Net 9.0.1 not working in WP8.1 Device

Tags: json.net

I'm getting the following exception when the json.net dll 9.0.1 is going to be loaded in my Windows Phone 10 (App compiled in ARM architecture), in the emulator it loads fine.

*"Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"*

I tried adding the dll manually but it has the same problem.

I ended up downgrading to version 8.0.3 which works perfectly.